# Swfobject embedswf - Movie not loaded

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

could anybody tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
<div id="position">
    <p>This is the place for showing the SWF(flash) file</p>
</div>

<script>
    swfobject.embedSWF("animations/standing.swf", "position", "250", "200", "9");
</script>
```

Some important notes that might help:

1 - This is a custom HTML module in Joomla, which is shown in a certain position

2 - folder named "animations" is in the root directory of website

3 - Actually this embed the position (height and width) correctly and the p element doesn't   show but the flash file does not play either. If I right click the position in which the flash should be shown, I see 2 options: 1 - Movie not loaded and 2 - About adobe flash...

4 - I used Static Publishing of SWFObject and it worked just fine but because I'm working a lot with flash files in this website I need Dynamic Publishing of SWFObject

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A few moments ago I figured out that this is the local problem. As it works correctly on sever. So what might be wrong with localhost? I'm using XAMPP

Comment: Did you try looking in your browsers console to see if there were any errors or warnings?  **F12** on IE,  **Ctr+Shift+i** on chrome

Comment: Yes, there is a 404 Not found error which says: GET http://localhost/our_indie_game/index.php/characters/animations/multi-punch.swf 404 (Not Found). I did notice this before but couldn't find it useful. Got any idea? multi-punch.swf is in the animation folder which is in the root of the website

Comment: localhost/our_indie_game/index.php/characters/animations/multi-punch.swf

Comment: Ok, so the issue then is the path is wrong.  As it should be: `localhost/animations/multi-punch.swf` instead of `localhost/our_indie_game/index.php/characters/animations/multi-punch.swf` but I'm really confused as to where it would be picking up the `characters` directory?

Comment: Might be easiest to just use the full path instead of a relative one, as the relative path is relative the containing web page, not the site root.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just now and the issue was, as the comments suggest, a bad path for the SWF file. In your case, it should be:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("/animations/standing.swf", "position", "250", "200", "9");
```

There is a missing slash at the beginning of the path. That should make it look for the SWF file in the root directory of the website.